# Extend a list based on its contents

Tags: python, list

Say I have a list like so:

`myList = ['this\n', 'is\n', 'sparta\n']`

How can I achieve the following result without creating a new list, doing some logic and copying it in...

`newList = ['this', '\n', 'is', '\n', 'sparta', '\n']`

Comment: Do *all* your input strings have a newline? Or is it simply the last character of each string you need to separate?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Some don't have the newline character but the ones that do always have them at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `str.partition()` to produce a list of elements when splitting just once on the newline, then skip all the empty results from that:

```
newList = [elem for word in myList for elem in word.partition('\n') if elem]
```

Demo:

```
>>> myList = ['this\n', 'is\n', 'sparta\n']
>>> [elem for word in myList for elem in word.partition('\n') if elem]
['this', '\n', 'is', '\n', 'sparta', '\n']
>>> myList = ['this\n', 'is', 'sparta\n']
>>> [elem for word in myList for elem in word.partition('\n') if elem]
['this', '\n', 'is', 'sparta', '\n']
```

Comment: Yeah I was wondering why I'm getting empty results when using partition, thanks - this works nicely

Comment: What is a good resource to actually understand what your code is doing. It looks really complex

Comment: Look into list comprehensions. In long form, it would look like this: http://pastebin.com/RMzGHf57

Comment: @Ogen read from left to right as if each statement is nested; `for word in myList` is the outermost, then comes `for elem in word.partition('\n')` then the `if` statement. The very leftmost expression is executed for each iteration provided the `if` test is true.